# "Being courageous " or "be courageous" - Which phrase subject is the correct one?

Tags: grammar

What is the correct sentence?

1/ Being courageous is the necessary condition for passing the challenge.

2/ Be courageous is the necessary condition for passing the challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Being courageous* is an *-ing* clause, which can be treated as a noun phrase, and stand as the subject of a sentence.

*Be courageous* is a tensed clause (which could be a whole sentence), and so cannot stand as the subject of a sentence.

However, the quotation "Be courageous" could be treated as a noun phrase, and people are not always careful about using quotes when they are logically required. So somebody might say *"Be courageous!" is the necessary condition for passing the challenge*, and they might write it down as your second sentence.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful and detailed. Thank you very much!